# Simple EF query for a gridview?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

Total ef newbie question - given this simple Entity Model, how would I set up a simple query to display all clients in a gridview? Or display all clients with a zip in a given range?

```
public class scheduleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<client> clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<appt> appts { get; set; }
}

public class client
{
    public int clientID { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }
    public String email { get; set; }    
}

public class appt
{
    public int apptID { get; set; }
    public int clientID { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
scheduleContext schedule = new scheduleContext();
var q = from p in schedule.appts where select p; //this throws an error

GridView1.DataSource = schedule.appts.Load(); //load what??
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: First of all, what are you doing with the q variable? It isn't being used. It has a mistake after the `where` clause. You can remove the where keyword since you're not filtering by anything. Next, where is the zip field located in your class model?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an EntityDataSource control?  Using this control allows you to use LINQ to query your object model as well as support paging and sorting within your grid view.

Let's look at an example:

```
<asp:entitydatasource
    id="clientDataSource"
    contexttypename="scheduleContext.Example, Example"
    entitysetname="clients"
    runat="server" 
/>

<asp:gridview
    datasourceid="clientDataSource"
    allowpaging="true"
    allowsorting="true"
    pagesize="20"
    runat="server">

    <asp:boundfield datafield="name" headertext="Name" sortexpression="name" />
    <asp:boundfield datafield="email" headertext="Email" sortexpression="email" />
</asp:gridview>
```

There are many different ways to configure the [EntityDatasource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.aspx) to allow you do set filters, select specific columns, etc.

There are plenty of examples and tips regarding these controls, these are just a few:

- [Tutorial: Entity Data Source Control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/06/18/tutorial-entity-data-source-control.aspx)
- [EntityDataSource Quickstart Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668221.aspx)